# How to compute datatable with multiple filters?

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to sum the value of a certain column on my `datatable`, where column x is equal to a value AND column y is equal to another value.  I can implement this when I just filter on column X as follows:

```
dt.Compute("Sum([Cost])", "[COLUMNX] = 'blah'");
```

This works fine, however I now want to add another column to the filter, so something like `dt.Compute("Sum([Cost])", "[COLUMNX] = 'blah'", "[COLUMNY] = 'blah'");`

How can I filter on two different columns please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `AND` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
dt.Compute("Sum([Cost])", "[COLUMNX] = 'blah' AND [COLUMNY] = 'blah'");
```

or with LInq-To-DataTable which has no limits:

```
double sumCost = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("COLUMNX")=="blah" && r.Field<string>("COLUMNY")=="blah")
    .Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Cost"));
```

Comment: Doh! should have known it would have been as simple as an and!